# Bold a Range of Text in Swift WITHOUT Setting Specific Font (OSX)

Tags: swift, macos

I'm trying to convert this code sample to use on an OSX app:

```
func applyStylesToRange(searchRange: NSRange) {
    let fontDescriptor = UIFontDescriptor.preferredFontDescriptorWithTextStyle(UIFontTextStyleBody)
    let boldFontDescriptor = fontDescriptor.fontDescriptorWithSymbolicTraits(.TraitBold)
    let boldFont = UIFont(descriptor: boldFontDescriptor, size: 0)
    let normalFont = UIFont.preferredFontForTextStyle(UIFontTextStyleBody)

    let regexStr = "(\\*\\w+(\\s\\w+)*\\*)"
    let regex = NSRegularExpression(pattern: regexStr, options: nil, error: nil)!
    let boldAttributes = [NSFontAttributeName : boldFont]
    let normalAttributes = [NSFontAttributeName : normalFont]

    regex.enumerateMatchesInString(backingStore.string, options: nil, range: searchRange) {
        match, flags, stop in
        let matchRange = match.rangeAtIndex(1)
        self.addAttributes(boldAttributes, range: matchRange)

        let maxRange = matchRange.location + matchRange.length
        if maxRange + 1 < self.length {
          self.addAttributes(normalAttributes, range: NSMakeRange(maxRange, 1))
        }
    }
}
```

Some of the font descriptor methods used to grab the user-defined font don't seem to exist for OSX. All the examples of solving this problem that I can find involve using "boldSystemFontOfSize()", but I don't want to explicitly set a font size for the bolded text.

I found several partial solutions, such as using the following for the first part:

```
let fontManager = NSFontManager.sharedFontManager()
let normalFont = NSFont.userFontOfSize(0)
let boldFont = fontManager.convertFont(normalFont!, toHaveTrait: .BoldFontMask)
```

The problem with this is that the text that matches the regex (and is therefore bolded) does not respond to user-initiated font changes (both face and size). And there doesn't seem to be a convenient NSNotificationCenter message for when user changes font size for OSX, as there is for iOS.